# How to return IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net

I am still learning the basics of C# and found a task where you have to implement the method below, it is supposed to return the same sequence of strings but uppercase, and I assume by sequence it means an array.

But I am also somehow supposed to use IEnumerable for this.

I thought IEnumerable was an interface, how is it a type and a parameter in that method I am supposed to add logic into?

I searched and found that return type IEnumerable means it has to return something that can implement IEnumerable, but the parameters still confuse me, how do I use them to return uppercase? Do I use a `foreach` ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EnumerableTask
{
    public class EnumerableManipulation
    {
        /// <summary> Transforms all strings to upper case.</summary>
        /// <param name="data">Source string sequence.</param>

        public IEnumerable<string> GetUppercaseStrings(IEnumerable<string> data)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: try return data.Select( d => d.ToUpper())

Comment: @CetinBasoz If you have an answer, post an answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 this isn't an answer, it's a comment. The OP is confused about what IEnumerable is and how it relates to `IEnumerable<T>`. The answer to that isn't `use data.Select()`

Comment: OK I thought it wasn't worth to add it as an answer, I will.

Comment: @CetinBasoz the OP is confused about IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>. It's not enough to just tell them to use LINQ (which they won't know about either). To really help you'll have to explain this a bit

Comment: `IEnumerable` isn't just any old interface, there is special support for in the form of LINQ (the `data.Select(...)` method alluded to earlier) and iterators (`yield`) statements. You are almost never required to explicitly implement `IEnumerable` yourself, and indeed in this case you wouldn't need to do that either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't think we need to duplicate Linq documentation here.

Comment: btw it can be `void` method and you can update `IEnumerable<string> data` it's a reference type variable...

Comment: @Alp: since strings are immutable and `IEnumerable` is a forward-only view of data, that would be quite a feat. At the very least this would require `ICollection`, but `IList` would be more obvious. In any case this would be beyond the scope of the exercise.

Comment: Since we are adding unnecessary details, you could simply create a method getting a string and returning a string after any modification you want (like upper casing), and then  simply use it as a delegate in select on your IEnumerable. ie: data.Select(MyUpperCasingMethod).

Comment: @akzol: You should read all these comments and answers and try to understand them (looking stuff up when you don't understand something).  This is a good introduction to the importance of `IEnumerable<T>` in the framework.  That interface, LINQ, `yield return`, etc.  are all very important topics

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq Select() which would return an IEnumerable. ie:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUppercaseStrings(IEnumerable<string> data)
        {
          return data.Select(d => d.ToUpper());
        }
```

EDIT: You can check Linq documentation or my blog starting from the oldest post (Feb 2009) at:

[FoxSharp](https://cetinbasoz.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `foreach` and `yield`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUppercaseStrings(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
  foreach (var item in data) 
    yield return item?.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Side note: `?.ToUpper();` instead of `.ToUpper();` will be null safe.

Comment: @AndreiTătar So, just to make sure, we are using foreach because of the IEnumerable return type or parameter, right? 

Basically, it seems to me one would want to add IEnumerable as return type or parameter if they only want to pass something that can implement IEnumerable. 

Why else would you wanna use IEnumerable as a return type or parameter?

Comment: @Akzhol, foreach is not needed to make an IEnumerable. Check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: @Akzhol `IEnumerable` is an interface. An abstraction for something that can be enumerated. The generic variant provides more type safety. `foreach` just provides an easy way to iterate through it. I'm sure you can think of reasons of why you would use it. It works for anything you can enumerate (lists/array/db cursors/lines from a file/etc.). The good thing of IEnumerable is that it's lazily evaluated. For example when reading all the lines from a file - the naive implementation is to read the entire file and process the entire file - the correct one is to read and process line by line.

Comment: @AndreiTătar: A better way to state your last point might be: _"the correct one is **likely** to read and process line by line"_.  Sometimes, the correct course of action is to hungrily read everything - rare, yes, but possible

Comment: @Flydog57 I agree, but can't edit my comment anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a generic interface. It represents a collection of objects  of type `T`. In your case, `data` is a collection of `string` that can be enumerated.

### Enumerate a IEnumerable

To enumerate through the 'data' and acccess the elements one after the others, there is several possibilities. Here are two examples.

**GetEnumerator()**

`GetEnumerator()` gives you a way to enumerate through the `IEnumerable<T>`. `enumerator.Current` allows you to access the current element and `enumerator.MoveNext()` gives you a way to move to the next element in the collection.
At first use call `MoveNext()` method to place the enumerator at the first element of the `IEnumerable<T>`. While there is still elements to enumerate, `MoveNext()` will return `true`. When the end is reached, `MoveNext()` returns `false`.
Here is an example of how it is typically used.

```
IEnumerator<string> enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    string text = data.Current;
    /* Do something */
}
enumerator.Dispose();
```

**foreach**

Using `foreach` takes care of all the complexity of the enumerator process. It is in fact recommended to use `foreach` instead of directly manipulating the enumerator (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=net-6.0), in Remarks).

```
foreach(string text in data)
{
    /* Do something */
}
```

### Return a IEnumerable

Because `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface, you cannot "construct" it as you would  with a `class` or a `struct`. Hence to return a `IEnumerable<T>`, you have to instanciate an actual `class` or a `struct` that implements this interface. For example:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Foo()
{
    List<string> list =  new List<string>();
    /* Do something on the list*/
    return list;
}
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<string> Foo(int count)
{
    string[] array =  new string[count];
    /* Do something on the array*/
    return array;
}
```

You can do this because `List<T>` and `Array` implement the interface `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: I assume this is still a work in progress, but there is almost never a need for calling `.GetEnumerator()` directly. If you *do* call it, though, you have to make sure to dispose it properly, and you also want to use the generic version (`IEnumerator<string>`), since `IEnumerator` is even less comfortable to use. I personally wouldn't bother to mention `.GetEnumerator()` except in the context of explaining the internals of `foreach`.

Comment: I felt that it was interesting to present the enumerator process because it gives an understanding of what is an `IEnumerable<T>` . In addition, it allows to iterate every two elements for example.

Comment: Yes, there are scenarios where it's useful (or even necessary) to access `IEnumerator` "manually". That said, you still need a `using IEnumerator<string> enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();` here (or a block in older versions of C#) -- part of the semantics of `foreach` is that the enumerator is disposed if it implements the disposable pattern, which becomes important when enumerating things like rowsets from database queries.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Updated for Dispose().

Comment: @nrmontagne So I suppose every foreach is actually GetEnumerator under covers. But I still don't really understand the usage of IEnumerable as a parameter or as a return type, why would one do that and what does it mean?

Comment: Simply calling `.Dispose()` is not correct either. That would need a `try { .. } finally { enumerator.Dispose(); }`. You start to see why direct use of `.GetEnumerator()` is involved. :P The full pattern can be found in the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement), it is rather subtle.

Comment: @Akzhol, your question is twofold.
Using `IEnumerable<T>`  as a parameter provides a lot of freedom for the user of the method. It allows to provide different type of data . It does not constrain you to provide a `List<T>` when you were manipulating an `Array`.
Then using `IEnumerable<T>` as a return type meand that the returned collectionshould be enumerated but not altered. Many times, you will need to enumerate the collection once and then dispose it, because you are only fetching specific information.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is my understanding that the two options work fine (I have been using both process). How ever, if i understand, you are arguing that the options are not equivalent (which i don't claim), and that the first process is not error proof in some context.

Comment: If an exception occurs during processing, then `Dispose()` will never be called in your code. When using `try .. finally` or `using` this won't happen (`using` is itself shorthand for `try { ... } finally { object?.Dispose(); }`.